# How to upload 2 different file types via the same form php

Tags: php, html

my form looks like this

```
<form action='uploadFile.php' method='POST'>

                    <p>select an image</p>
                    <p style='font-size: 10px'>280x280px</p>
                    <input type='file' name='imageFile' />


                    <p>select it</p>
                    <input type='file' name='uploadFile'/>
                    <p>title it</p>
                    <input type='text' id='post-title' name='title'/>
                    <p>tag it</p>
                    <input type='text' id='post-tags' name='tags'/><br />
                    <button id='submit-file'>submit it</button>

</form>
```

the php back end looks like

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']))
{
if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['size']))
{
```

and

```
if(isset($_FILES['imageFile']['size']))
{
if(isset($_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name']))
{
```

basically long story short; on submission the else statement to the if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']) and if(isset($_FILES['imageFile']['size'] is triggered (confirmed via echo statements) on both regardless of which is submitted . any idea on what would cause this?

Comment: don't forget `<form>`'s `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute

Comment: why not use the multi file upload

Comment: @Kris Roofe; the user needs to specify the file type for each upload type; I saw the various posts with the loop which is why I wanted to go this route;  it seemed that the upload for the loop was a user has to press shift and select multiples which doesn't seem to be a fair thing for the users.

Comment: you can category them in the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html form tag must contain enctype="multipart/form-data" to upload a file.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed enctype in your  tag. It requires enctype="multipart/form-data" to upload files.

```
<form action="uploadFile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The following PHP helps to find whether file is given for upload or not:

```
// For imageFile
if (isset($_FILES['imageFile']) && $_FILES['imageFile']['size'] != 0) {
    // input file selected for upload)
} else {
    // input file not selected for upload
}

// For uploadFile
if (isset($_FILES['uploadFile']) && $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'] != 0) {
    // input file selected for upload)
} else {
    // input file not selected for upload
}
```